# Returning a Date Range based on Day of the Month

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select * 
From Orders

WHERE   (
        extract(day from sysdate)<=21          
        and 
        to_date(SCHEDULEDATE , 'yyyy/mm/dd') between 
        to_date((to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY')||'/'||cast((extract(month from sysdate)-1)as char)||'/22'),'yyyy/mm/dd') and to_date((to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')||'/'||cast((extract(month from sysdate))as char)||'/21'),'yyyy/mm/dd')
       )
      or
      (

       extract(day from sysdate)>21 
       and 
       to_date(SCHEDULEDATE , 'yyyy/mm/dd') between 
       to_date((to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY')||'/'||cast((extract(month from sysdate))as char)||'/22'),'yyyy/mm/dd') and to_date((to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY')||'/'||cast((extract(month from sysdate)+1)as char)||'/21'),'yyyy/mm/dd')
    )
```

I'm trying to figure out a simple way of returning a set of date ranges based on the day of the Month. If the Day of the month of less than or Equal to I want it to return all orders the have a schedule date between the 22 of the Month before and the 21st of the Current month. If the Day of the month is greater than 21 I would like it return all orders that have a schedule date of the current month up to the end of the month. I've tried to use a case in the where with no luck. What I have now doesn't seem to work either. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
WHERE (extract(day from sysdate) <= 21 and  
       scheduledate >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'), -1) + 21 and  
       scheduledate < trunc(sysdate, 'MON') + 21
      ) or
      (extract(day from sysdate) > 21 and
       trunc(scheduledate, 'MON') = trunc(sysdate, 'MON')
      )
```

Comment: thanks Gordon, I wanted to add a condition after the where statement but it seems to ignore it , example          and  status <> 'Canceled' do i need to  enclose that somewhere in the where ?

Comment: I figured it out, just needed an extra set of parenthesis.